# Calling geotools' SimpleFeatureCollection.features() one too many times results in "Maximum lock count exceeded"

Tags: java, geotools

I create `geotools`' `SimpleFeatureCollection` from a shape file on HDD once.  I then call its `.features()` method a ton of times.  So far I believed that this was good practice, but it appears not to be.  After calling the feature method one too many times, I receive

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Maximum lock count exceeded
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.fullTryAcquireShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:528)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryAcquireShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:488)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1282)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
 at org.geotools.data.shapefile.files.ShpFiles.acquireRead(ShpFiles.java:358)
 at org.geotools.data.shapefile.files.ShpFiles.getReadChannel(ShpFiles.java:789)
 at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.<init>(ShapefileReader.java:253)
 at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileSetManager.openShapeReader(ShapefileSetManager.java:51)
 at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(ShapefileFeatureSource.java:263)
 at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureStore.getReaderInternal(ShapefileFeatureStore.java:124)
 at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:563)
 at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:165)
```

How can I avoid this from happening?  What is good coding practice here?  Should I use the shape file to create the `SimpleFeatureCollection` every time before calling its `.features()` method?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [javadocs](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/FeatureIterator.html) make clear you must close a `FeatureIterator` after use or resources will become exhausted or leaked. You need to use code like this:

```
FeatureIterator i = featureCollection.features()
 try {
    while( i.hasNext() ){
        SimpleFeature feature = i.next();
    }
 }
 finally {
    i.close();
 }
```

Comment: Eureka!  This solved it.  Thank you very much.  I have never closed an iterator before, but there is always a first.  Are iterators to be closed in general, or is it just this one which requires closing?

Comment: Just these ones as they have real resources under them